# XAMPP configuration page missing

Tags: xampp

Today I installed XAMPP (v5.6.15). Everything seems to be okay but the **old orange configuration page is missing** (localhost/xampp/index.php). 
Now I don't know how to change security settings (such as MySQL password...).

Is there a way to bring back configuration page?

Comment: While i do not know how to return the page, a lot of the settings can be changed in xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc file

Answer (score 1):

The old orange XAMPP administration page is no longer included in current XAMPP versions. You cannot bring back the old orange start page unless you go back to using the older version.

As for changing the password without the Orange Page:

1. Start the Apache Server and MySQL instances from the XAMPP control panel.
2. Open phpMyAdmin: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`.
3. In the phpMyAdmin window, select SQL tab from the right panel. This will open the SQL tab where we can run the SQL queries.
   Now type the following query in the textarea:
   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';`
   Click Go. You will see a message saying that the query has been executed successfully.
   If you refresh the page, you will get an error message. The phpMyAdmin configuration file is not aware of our newly set root passoword. We have to modify the phpMyAdmin config file.
4. Open the file `[XAMPP Installation Path] / phpmyadmin / config.inc.php` in your favorite text editor.
5. Search for the string `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`
   Change to:  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';`
   Here the 'password' is what we set to the root user using the SQL query.
6. Save the config.inc.php file and RESTART the XAMPP server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful and got me over a hump.  Any idea as to why this was removed?  It seems like a valuable tool is gone, life is less simple now.